# Calculating the trigger time for an alarm when today set time passed in android?

Tags: android

In my Alarm application i have the following function for calculating the trigger time for the alarm , and its working perfect if the alarm time > current time , but if the alarm time is passed " Today Set time passed" current time > alarm time the alarm should fires tomorrow but in my function it fires  in the same day  after a few hours or minutes based on the difference amount . How can i fix this problem?  what is the condition i should add to my function to wait 24 hours to tomorrow if the alarm set time is passed ? please help me

```
private long getTriggerTime(int  hour,int minute)
{

  long triggerTime = System.currentTimeMillis() ;
  Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();
  int  currentHour = calendarNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
  int  currentMinute = calendarNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


  int HourDifference = currentHour-hour;
  int MinuteDifference = currentMinute -minute;

  if(HourDifference < 0 ){ HourDifference = HourDifference*(-1);  }
  if(MinuteDifference < 0){ MinuteDifference = MinuteDifference*(-1); }

   triggerTime = triggerTime + ( HourDifference*60*60*1000) + (MinuteDifference*60*1000 );


   return  triggerTime; 
 }
```

**Here how i use this function**

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTriggerTime(hour,min),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY ,sender);
```

Note : hour , min in  24hour format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the sample code for alarm to fire if the alarm time > current time ,else it will for 24 hours.....

```
private long getAlarmTimeInMillis(int  hour,int minute){
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);//
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if (calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System
                    .currentTimeMillis()) {
       calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+ 1);
            // add 24 hours to the calender.getTimeMillis
    }
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}
```

try this.....

Comment: @santhoshthanks for helping me , i tried it but i have errors on defaultTimeZone, and gmtTime ??

Comment: How do you define these variables??

Comment: thanks ,I tried it , when the  alarm time > current time , the alarm  triggered directly after setting it it didn't wait

Comment: for this reason i have used the hourdifference in my function to prevent the alarm from triggering directly

Comment: when i debug the app , it enters in the if condition in all cases i mean if the current time < alarm time " the alarm time not passed " it will enter in the if statement ! can you help me more to fix that please ?

Comment: sorry for the inconvinence,i have updated the above code try with that code

Comment: @ santhoshthanks a lot, the problem solved the alarm wait , not triggered directly and i have set an alarm for tomorrow , if its fired successfully i will accept your answer .

Comment: but don't switch off your phone because alarm manager will be reset when phone is switched off..i will wait for your acceptance

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();



calendarNow.set(calendarNow.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendarNow.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                calendarNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                                calendarNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                calendarNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE), 0);


 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            calendarNow.getTimeInMillis(),
                            24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```